# Is this weighted least squares or just weighting the dependent variable

Tags: econometrics, labor-economics, regression, heteroskedasticity

I am a little confused as to what the following line means. Do the authors mean they run a weighted least squares using the sample size as weights, or just weight the dependent variable using the sample size?

[image]

Here's the link to the original paper. The part I'm talking about is in page 19:

https://www.barcelonagse.eu/sites/default/files/working_paper_pdfs/783.pdf

Comment: I won't offer a genuine contribution to this, because a serious treatment requires more time than I have. But it appears the 'weighting' has nothing to do with the removal of heteroskedasticity (i.e. weighting the error to make it homoskedastic), but more to do with a weighting process conducted on the data, in order for the sample to more accurately represent the population. I hope even if the statement I made is misguided, that it prompts thought/discussion.